# Changing username

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using `accounts-password` module and as written in meteor documentation I wanted to call `Accounts.setUsername(userId,newUsername)` from within a method. However, I'm getting `setUsername(..) is not a method` error.

[image]

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Here is the list of installed packages

[image]

**EDIT 2:** So apparently the method does get called and it works as expected, however, it throws error in browser console anyway (at the same time `WebStorm` marks the method as unknown)

[image]

Comment: Because the function is `Accounts.setUsername` and not `setUsername`?

Comment: Are you trying to call this function from the client side? This is a server side only function.

Comment: @DavidWeldon sorry if I confused you, I am calling `Accounts.setUsername`

Comment: @BrianShamblen I'm calling it from within a method defined in `Meteor.methods({})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably happening because your Meteor.methods are in a shared (client and server executable) location.  If that's the case, you can either put this particular method in a server-only location (in your /server folder), or wrap the Accounts.setUsername method in an `if(Meteor.isServer) { ... }`

Comment: That's a very good point. Methods can be in server-only location?

Comment: Yep, put them in your /server folder at the root of your project.

Comment: Ah I thought I read somewhere in the docs methods must be available to both client and server